# Histogram with predefined bins in R

Tags: r

I have vector containing numbers (18 20 21 22 24 26 27 34 35 35)

Now I need to build table with

- frequency distribution
- relative frequency distribution

by predefined bins (16-20, 21-25, 26-30, 31-35)

And plot histogram according to these bins

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hist` with specified `breaks`. For example:

```
numbers = c(18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 34, 35, 35)
hist(numbers, breaks = seq(15, 35, length.out = 5))
```

[image]